# How set up default values in Django forms choice field?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to set up some default values in a django form choicefield where i ask for the user his birthdate and the city where he lives, i already tried pass the parameter "initial" in the form and add an attribute value but is not working.

here is my code...

forms.py

```
class RegisterForm2(forms.Form):
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices = gender_choices,required=True)

    birthdate = forms.DateField(widget 
                =forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1900, 2020)))

    marital_status = forms.ChoiceField(choices = marital_status, 
                     required=True)

    districts = forms.ChoiceField(choices = districts, required=True)

    city = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs= 
       {'id':'id_cidade', 'placeholder':'Nome da cidade onde vives'}))

    job = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs= 
          {'id':'id_profissao', 'placeholder':'A tua Profissão'}))

    class meta:
        model = UserRegister
        fields = ['gender',
              'birthdate',
              'marital_status',
              'districts',
              'city',
              'job']
```

choices.py

```
gender_choices = (('F', 'Feminino'), ('M', 'Masculino'))

marital_status = (('S','Solteiro'), ('D', 'Divorciado'), ('V', 
                                       'Viuvo'), ('C', 'Casado'))

districts = (('Aveiro','Aveiro'), ('Beja','Beja'), ('Braga','Braga'), 
        ('Bragança','Bragança'), ('Castelo Branco','Castelo Branco'),
        ('Coimbra','Coimbra'), ('Évora', 'Évora'),('Faro','Faro'), 
('Guarda','Guarda'),('Ilha da Madeira','Ilha da Madeira'),('Ilha dos 
Açores','Ilha dos Açores'),('Leiria','Leiria'),('Lisboa','Lisboa'), 
         ('Portalegre','Portalegre'),('Porto','Porto'), 
('Santarém','Santarém'),('Setúbal','Setúbal'),('Viana do 
Castelo','Viana do Castelo'),
         ('Vila Real','Vila Real'),('Viseu','Viseu'))
```

Comment: Where did you try that? Show the code.

Comment: districts = forms.ChoiceField(initial = "select", choices = districts, required=True)

Comment: Sorry for that..

Comment: But "select" is not one of the possible values for the districts fields. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: hum... i didn't know that shoud be in the districts lists now it works... By the way how could i do that in the datefield like showing "day", "month", "year" in the fields?... this is the code : birthdate = forms.DateField(widget = forms.SelectDateWidget( years=range(1900, 2020)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by default ChoiceField initial value is the it's 1st tuple, if you and any initial value pass the value as fast tuple .

```
gender_choices = (('initial', "choose"),('F', 'Feminino'), ('M', 'Masculino'))
```

Comment: yup that's it... Do you know how can i do the same here ? forms.DateField(widget = forms.SelectDateWidget( years=range(1900, 2020)))... have a inicitial value instead numbers and name of the month

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
MALE = 'M'
FEMALE = 'F'
gender_choices = (
           (MALE, 'Feminino'), 
           (FEMALE, 'Masculino'))
```

do like this for all choices this should work.